# Job Quartz and Thread Runnable cannot be run at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-data-jpa, quartz-scheduler

I'm facing a timing issue when running a job.

I have more than 1000 jobs running at the same time on the fifth second of every minute `(5 * * ? * * *)`, which means more than 1000 jobs are running every minute.
I am combining with Thread Runnable to run all the jobs in parallel, but the result is not what I want.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=projectName
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=100
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
```

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // code
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

My current result is on the left | The result I want is on the right

```
2021-08-11 12:40:06     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:06     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:07     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:07     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:07     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:08     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:08     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:08     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:08     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:09     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:09     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:10     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:10     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:10     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:10     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:10     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:10     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:10     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:10     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
2021-08-11 12:40:11     |   2021-08-11 12:40:05
... + 1second           |   ... 12:40:05
```

How to run more than 1000 jobs but the start time is the same?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need the start times to be similar?

Comment: I want all the work to be completed within the first 30s, because if not started at a certain time then the work after that will not be done because it keeps adding 1 second.
I am making a system for an exchange and the exchange only allows placing orders within the first 30 seconds of every minute, if it is more than 30 seconds without doing all the work, it will run in the wrong flow.

Answer (score 1):

Starting 1000+ new threads is expensive, and doesn't necessarily get you more parallelism than having one thread per core (depending on how much time each thread spends blocked on IO).

I would try a single Quartz job, with a fixed size thread pool with < 100 pre-created threads. Submit your 1000+ jobs to that thread pool. You can tune the exact number of threads for a compromise between context switching overhead and parallelism.

Comment: Can you get a sample code of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample;

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);

@Scheduled(cron = "5 * * * * *")
void justWait() throws Exception {
    
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).parallel().forEach(
            i -> {
                try {
                    executorService.submit(() -> System.out.println(new Date() + ":" + i)).get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    );
}

@Test
void justWait2() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000*60*5);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply,
How to distinguish between different jobs to process, or do I have to use query to get the list and put it in the loop inside executorService.submit

Comment: You can use the index. For example if you have an array of currency pairs, each thread will run for one of these symbol which is provided as the array index (i.e. the i variable in the example)

Comment: ```
List<User> listUser = userRepository.findByEmail("email");
 ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
 
 @Scheduled(cron = "5 * * * * *")
 void justWait() throws Exception {
     
     IntStream.rangeClosed(1, listUser.size()).parallel().forEach(
             i -> {
                 try {
                     executorService.submit(() -> {
                      User user = listUser.get(i);
                     });
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
     );
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, with the example code above

Comment: Although this is also true, you can simplify it by using listUser.stream().parallel().forEach( u ... where u is the user object...

Comment: so I won't need to use quartz library anymore, because this can help me to run all jobs in parallel, using @Scheduled(cron = "5 * * * * *") of spring boot

Comment: It is also quartz with "spring way" initialization. Please do not forget to add @EnableScheduling annotation to your class...

Comment: Although, I tried the way you said above but I found it is the same as the first time, also can't run all at the same time, or because my internal processing code is too much so it there is still time delay.
```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
@Scheduled(cron = "5 * * ? * *")
public void scheduledTasks() {
 List<Bet> listBet = betRepository.findByStatus(BetStatus.RUNNING);
 
 listBet.stream().parallel().forEach(i ->{
  try {
   executorService.submit(() -> {

   })
  } catch(Exception){
   
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: You may try different treadpool sizes to find the optimal execution time, but if your processing code is too long, then at some point you probably need to scale up your system or try to use an other architecture like pub/sub queues instead of cron jobs...

Answer (score 0):

I am using Job Quartz and save jobs under database, and every fifth second it will trigger method ***public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)*** to run, I am not using SpringBoot Scheduling Task

```
public Scheduler addAndStartWefinexJob(String betId) {
        try {
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(betId,"Exchanges").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("5 * * ? * * *")).build();
            JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(WefinexJob.class).withIdentity(betId, "Exchanges") .build();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            System.out.println(jobDetail.getKey() + ","+ trigger.getKey() + " will run at: " + new Date());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return scheduler;
    }
    
    public boolean deleteJobDetail(String name) {
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            flag = scheduler.deleteJob(jobKey(name, "Exchanges"));
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return flag;
    }
```